# EditorInfo null after startActivity from InputMethodService

Tags: java, android, input

I am having the following problem. My InputMethodService starts an Activity through startActivity and I have a ResultsReceiver that gets a result from the Acivity. I want this result to get printed out in the chatbox with commitText(). This didn't work in the sense that nothing was printed out.

Next I checked getCurrentEditorInput().dump() and noticed that a lot of the values are null. So I am thinking the Editor is somehow broken and that's why it doesn't work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306657/inputconnection-committext-doesnt-work-in-my-resultreceiver)  is some of the relevant code for reference.

I am pretty frustrated with being not able to fix that. Does anyone have any idea or knowledge if one can fix that?

Comment: Yeah I checked that one but it sadly didn't work. :(

Comment: Sorry, yeah EditorInfo isn't valid. I have an idea though for a workaround. I will start the Service again from the Activity an pass all the text that was in the hatbox previously

Comment: If I start onStartInputView then I need to pass EditorInfo. But as we saw the EditorInfo isn't valid, so yeah...

Comment: ok, so I think I misunderstood you suggestion. I called onStartInputView after I get my result in the Service with the EditorInfo which I saved beforehand globally. But this is not what you meant right?

Comment: Ok, I just saw the onStartInputView is overridden and it gets called when the service starts basically.

Comment: I will try out the Handler solution in your link though. seems promising.

Comment: yeah I did right now, but this for sure doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

If you start an Activity, the connection to the edit text will be broken because its no longer focused.  The framework simply doesn't expect you to launch an Activity.  I'm not even sure if launching a dialog instead would fix it, because by touching an element to make a selection, you're changing the focus.  What you're trying to do isn't really supported.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Do you have any idea on how to work around that?

Comment: Doing it on a delay via posting to a handler might give it time to reestablish the connection. Other than that, no